# GCC compile error

Tags: c, gcc, openacc, offloading

I am trying to build and run GCC. After trying to build it a couple different ways I got it to build, however when I try to compile code (example:)

```
gcc -fopenacc -foffload=nvptx-none -o foo foo.c
```

with it I get this error:

```
lto-wrapper fatal error problem with building target image for nvptx-none
```

I tried to ask the internet for this question, and while others have reported this issue, there has been no solutions posted. I am using GCC6.

Comment: Is the `=3D` by any chance an encoding of an `=` copied from a mail message, so in fact you should be writing `-foffload=nvptx-none`?  It probably isn't that, but it is one peculiar possibility that we may as well eliminate up front.  And the error message does mention `nvptx-none` and not `3Dnvptx-none` which gives the suggestion more force.  I see [jcoppens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1545014/jcoppens) is of the opinion that this was correct.

Comment: Edited the gcc command line. The original had =3D, which I suspect is (was) an escape code.

Comment: Have you ever used the `-foffload=anything` option before?  Were you successful?  Have you installed whatever software (and/or hardware?) is required to support `-foffload=nvptx-none`?

Comment: Try adding `-fno-stack-protector`.

Comment: `g++ -O3 -fopenmp -fno-stack-protector foo.cpp`